# Error en routing de Angular

Tags: angular, routing

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en angular y al momento de intentar escribir el  me marca rojo y no me lo lee
adjunto imagen del error[image: app.component.html]

Comment: Mándanos tu componente TS.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas importar este modulo en `app.module.ts`:

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
```

Despues lo agregas a `imports[]`.

```
imports: [    RouterModule,  ]
```